# Google sign in, "An Internal error has occurred" appears after I published my app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, google-plus, google-account

My app works perfectly after I integrated Google+.
After I published it in Google Play, I am getting the "An Internal error has occurred" toast. What should I do?

Comment: What IDE you have used?

Comment: @NifrasIsmail I use Eclipse.